# Client cerificate authentication for a SharePoint 2007 web

Tags: sharepoint-2007, iis-6, moss, client-certificates

Is it possible to enable certificate authentication for a SharePoint 2007 web i.e. not for the entire site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not. Authentication providers are setup at the web application level and it is not more granular than that.